# What will be the value of nextState?

Tags: react-native

I am getting constant data from MQTT and I have to update the state constantly. So I was using shouldComponentUpdate for performance optimisation. Whenever I get an update of data I set the state variable. But whenever I try to do this

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) {
    console.log(this.state.status) //gives the correct output
    console.log(nextState.status) //gives me undefined
    return true
}
```

I am making the MQTT call in component did mount and it's updating the state like this

```
newStateArray = this.state.status.slice()
newStateArray[counter].status = config.appliance[item].status
this.setState({
    status: newStateArray
})
```

Due to that I'm not able to compare them and optimise the performance. Any reason why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)

This method determines whether or not to re-render when prop or state is changed.

**If you want to check the value,**

```js
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log("shouldComponentUpdate: " + JSON.stringify(nextProps) + " " + JSON.stringify(nextState));
        return true;
    }
```

In the example above, you must return true, but in actual use, you must make the necessary comparisons and return the values.

> Example: return nextState.id !== this.state.id;